# South: how to apply N migration without applying N-1

Tags: django, django-south

If I call `manage.py migrate app_name 51` it tries to migrate 50th too, but I don't need that. Will it work and is it OK if I just delete .py file with 50th migration and try again?

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete 00050_foo_bar.py named migration file ?

Comment: you can manually add  `50th migration` to your table migrations on data bases, so you cheat south to believe it was done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the answer is: migrate 50th migration with `--fake` flag and migrate the next one normally, or yeah I tried to delete the file and it works too.

Comment: It can be done exactly like this, but you can run into problems like table foo_bar is missing during running project, so I will suggest to delete migration and start from scratch "schemamigration app --initial" :)